# How to catch the event which is fired when "Save Work Item" button clicked in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, tfs-workitem

I would like to know if it is possible to catch the event which is fired when you click "Save Work Item" button in Visual Studio 2017 (which is responsible for saving the changes to TFS) from a different application/service.

[Save Work Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uk51.jpg)

Comment: Could you get useful information from Danie's suggestion?

Comment: It is completely a different approach than what I am looking for. Yes, Danie's suggestion works fine, However I am looking for a solution which works for VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/overview). Depending on what you want to accomplish, there may be an existing service hook, or you may need to write your own service and capture the event via a [web hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks).

You can't intercept this activity via Visual Studio, because work items can be modified via many different methods.

- REST API
- Web portal
- Visual Studio

It's also important to note that the ability to modify work items within Visual Studio is deprecated as of VS2017, and will be removed in an upcoming major release.